# Best way to compute DF of a phrase with Lucene

Tags: lucene, information-retrieval

How can one compute document frequency of a given **phrase** with Lucene (4.6)?

I found a way to compute DF for one term.
Is there something as elegant as this for phrases (1-5 words)?

```
val reader = IndexReader.open(IndexProperties.index)
println("Number of docs in index : " + reader.maxDoc())
val t = new Term("text", "братишка")
val df = reader.docFreq(t)
println("DF = " + df)
```

UPD: by *phrase* I mean a short sequence of terms that **must** occur in the document. Also they **must** go one after another in the text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like PhraseQuery is the solution.

```
for (termString <- splitted) {
  pq.add(new Term(IndexProperties.textField, termString))
}
pq.setSlop(0)

val collector = TopScoreDocCollector.create(5000, true)
searcher.search(pq, collector)
```

It is also important that `splitted : Array[String]` must be a result of your analyzer's tokenization.

Answer (score 0):

Java Code:

```
String phrase = "your phrase";
Query q = new Queryparser(Version.LUCENE_46, "field", analyzer).parse(phrase);
int df = new IndexSearher(reader).search(q, null).scoreDocs.length;
```

Comment: I get results without any of the words from phrase with such implementation. Which analyzer did you mean?

Comment: Should be the same analyzer as you used during indexing. e.g. StandardAnalyzer. I don't understand what you mean with "I get results without any of the words ...". My example returns you the DF for the terms "your" and "phrase" where the term phrase is exactly after the term "your".